# Prove $(S \circ R) \setminus (T \circ R) \subseteq (S \setminus T) \circ R$

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

> Suppose $R$ is a relation from $A$ to $B$ and $S$ and $T$ are relations from $B$
> to $C$.
>
> Prove $(S \circ R) \setminus (T \circ R) \subseteq (S \setminus T) \circ R$

Consider arbitrary element $(x,y)$

Suppose $(x,y) \in (S \circ R) \setminus (T \circ R)$

It follows that $(x,y) \in (S \circ R)$, and thus there are two elements, say $(x,a)$ and $(a,y)$, such that $(x,a) \in R$ and $(a,y) \in S$.

We also have $(x,y) \notin (T \circ R)$, which means we have three possibilities:

1. $(x,b) \in R$  and $(b,y) \notin T$
2. $(x,b) \notin R$  and $(b,y) \in T$
3. $(x,b) \notin R$  and $(b,y) \notin T$

Since $(x,a) \in R$, $(a,y) \notin T$.

Since $(a,y) \in S$, we have $(a,y) \in S \setminus T$, and therefore $(x,y) \in (S \setminus T) \circ R$

Arbitrary element was considered, so we have our result:

$$(S \circ R) \setminus (T \circ R) \subseteq (S \setminus T) \circ R$$

$\Box$

Is it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but personally instead of the three options I would write the definition of an ordered pair not being in  a composite relation:

$ \neg \exists b\in B.(<x,b> \in R \wedge <b,y> \in T) \Leftrightarrow \forall b \in B. \neg (<x,b> \in R \wedge <b,y> \in T) \Leftrightarrow \\ \forall b\in B.(<x,b> \in R \rightarrow \neg <b,y> \in T) $